# How to path to external (dynamic) assets with Vue-Loader / Webpack

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, vue.js

I have a project that accesses profile images dynamically from JSON retrieved from an API service. The problem is I'm having a tough time figuring out where in the file system to put these images during development and what the path should be in the JSON.

Here is a small example:

```
<template>
  <li :class="{'is-active': isActive}">
      <div class="responsible">
        <profile-picture :the-url="user.profilePicture" the-size="large"></profile-picture>
        {{ user.name }}
      </div>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
import ProfilePicture from '../components/ProfilePicture'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  },
  props: [
    'user'
  ],
  components: {
    'profile-picture': ProfilePicture
  }
}
</script>
```

So, what would be the path that `user.profilePicture` should have and where should that file be located in the filesystem? Again, I don't want to pack the image with webpack - I want this to come from a library of images that users have uploaded. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

They can go anywhere in your publicly visible folder (the one with `index.html` in it).  Then you just make the path relative to that, so if you put them in `public/images/users` the path would be `/images/users/filename.png`.

You could also have the `ProfilePicture` component handle the path, and just store the filename in your database.  So the database would store `filename.png` and your `ProfilePicture` component would know to add `/images/users/` to the beginning.  That way if you change the profile picture folder later you don't have to update DB records, just change the `ProfilePicture` component.  This is probably best.